# Convert a value of 8:00 to 8.00

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I want to convert a value of `8:00` to either a `8` OR a `8.00` so then I can multiply this number to another INT value such as `2`.

Right now I get a error message saying:

```
Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '8:00' to data type int.
```

I have tried `CAST(MYCOLUMN AS INT)` but it did not work.

Can you kindly help?

Best Regards,

Comment: Is 8:00 a time value, e.g. 8 o'clock? if that's the case, then you can't reliably convert just by replacing `:` -> `.`. 8:47 would actually be 8 + 47/60 = 8.7833333.

Comment: This value of 8:00 is stored as hours worked in the table, so if I see an employee working two days I would multiple 2 by 8:00 which is where I get the conversion error so that's I would like to replace 8:00 to an int value of 8.00. Hope this makes sense

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure what you're doing, however it is it actually a time and you want they hour you can do this.

```
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, CAST('8:00' AS TIME));
```

EDIT:

SQL 2005 doesn't have the TIME data type so you'd have to do this.

```
SELECT DATEPART(HOUR, CAST('1900-01-01 ' + '8:00' AS DATETIME));
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
CAST(replace(MYCOLUMN, ':', '.') AS float)
```

(This assumes that your internationalization settings interpret `.` as a decimal place.)

or

```
CAST(left(mycolumn, charindex(':', mycolumn) - 1) as int)
```